# How to sum items in a Node recursively in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to sum up items in a node both iteratively and recursively. I already wrote the program to do the iterative way and I'm having problems on how this can be done recursively.

code:

```
public int sumIterative() {
    Node newNode= new Node(item, next);
    int sum = 0;

    while(newNode != null){
        sum = sum + item;
        newNode = newNode.next;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

My effort on making the recursive way:

```
public int sumRecursive() {
    Node newNode = new Node(item,next);
    int sum = 0;
    int result;
    if(newNode == null){
        result = 0;
    } else {
        return sumRecursive();
    }
    return sum;    
}
```

I am trying to make this with the logic of "there are no nodes after this"

How is it possible for this to be done recursively?

Edit

This is the public driver method, I can post my whole code on demand

```
public int sumRecursive() {
    int sum = 0;
    if (top != null) {
        sum = top.sumRecursive();
    }
    return sum;
}

class LinkedList {

    private class Node {
        public int item;
        public Node next;

        public Node(int newItem, Node newNext)  {
            item = newItem;
            next = newNext;
        }

        public int getItem() {
            return item;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node newNext) {
            next = newNext;
        }

        // My Other Node methods

        // Recursively add up the numbers stored in this
        // and all the nodes after this.
        // Base case: there are no nodes after this.
        public int sumRecursive() {
            Node node = new Node(item,next);

            /*Node newNode = new Node(item,next);
            int sum = 0;
            if (null == newNode) {
                return sum;
            } else {
                sum += sumRecursive(newNode.next);
            }*/

            if (node == null) {
                return node.item;
            } else {
                return node.item + sumRecursive(node.next);
            }
        }

        // Iteratively add up the numbers stored in this
        // and all the nodes after this.
        public int sumIterative() {
            Node newNode= new Node(item, next);
            int sum = 0;

            while(newNode != null) {
                sum = sum + item;
                newNode = newNode.next;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    } // end class Node

    private Node top; // a pointer to the first node in the list (when it's not empty)

    public LinkedList() {
        top = null; // empty list
    }

    // Insert a node at the front of the list
    public void insertAtFront(int newItem)  {
        top = new Node(newItem, top);
    }

    // Print out the list (10 numbers per line)
    public void printList() {
        int count = 1;
        Node curr;

        if (top == null) {
            System.out.println( "List is empty" );
        } else {
            curr = top;
            while (curr != null) {
                System.out.print( " " + curr.item );
                count++;
                if (count % 10 == 0) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            if (count % 10 != 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    // public driver method for sumRecursive
    public int sumRecursive() {
        int sum = 0;

        if (top != null) {
            sum = top.sumRecursive();
        }

        return sum;
    }

    // public driver method for sumIterative
    public int sumIterative() {
        int sum = 0;

        if (top != null) {
            sum = top.sumIterative();
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this method defined in some LinkedList type class? Otherwise, what is `top`?

Comment: i updated it @cricket_007

Answer (score 3):

```
public int sumRecursive() {
  return sumRecursive(top);
}    

public int sumRecursive(Node node){
  if (node == null) {
    return 0;
  }
  return node.item + sumRecursive(node.next);
}
```

// or to match your driver function

```
public int sumRecursive() {
  if (top == null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return top.sumRecursive();
  }
}    

// in Node class    
public int sumRecursive(){ 
  int sum = this.item;  
  if (this.next != null) {
    sum += this.next.sumRecursive();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int sumRecursive(Node node){
        if(node == null){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return node.item + sumRecursive(node.next);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What is node.item of null?

Comment: I had a problem with this because the public driver method is not the same as this,  I made an edit, it should show now

Comment: Now what if the first element is null?

Comment: Getting better. Still there's no point in testing `node.next==null` (except saving one recursive call).

Comment: This is awkward... was completely out of focus.